# Differentiation of unit force vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I was reading a paper and don't know how the following was derived. Given that $f =         \begin{bmatrix}
        \ddot{x} \\
        \ddot{y} \\
        \ddot{z} + g \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $v =         \begin{bmatrix}
        \dddot{x} \\
        \dddot{y} \\
        \dddot{z} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$, I thought that $\frac{\dot{f}}{\lVert f\rVert}$ would be equal to $\frac{v}{\lVert f\rVert}$. However, the equation in the paper states that $\frac{\dot{f}}{\lVert f\rVert} = \frac{v}{\lVert f\rVert} - \frac{ff^Tv}{\lVert f\rVert^3}$. I don't understand where the second term comes from and am not sure where to start. Could someone help explain this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it actually $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot f}{\lVert f\rVert}\right)$? That seems like "differentiation of the unit force vector" to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done the math, but that looks like it is coming from the **total differential** of $f$. I suppose $f$ is a force vector of a moving body? Some more context information would be useful.